# Socket Programming in Java Handling with ReadLine Exception

Tags: java, sockets, exception, networking, readline

I am new to socket programming and trying to figure out an exception handling problem. I can't send a string message to a server from a client in java because the readLine part of my code gives exception error when I run the program. I tried throwing Exception in my Server class and get no red underlined code error while running the server program, but when I run the client program after server program, I got exception error in the br.readLine section of my code. What might be the cause?

My client code:

```
package com.soc;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 9999;// 0-1023 to 65535
    Socket s = new Socket(ip,port);

    String str = "Hello World";

    OutputStreamWriter os = newOutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os);
    os.write(str);
    os.flush(); 
}
```

}

My server code:

```
package com.soc;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    System.out.println("Server is started");
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9999);

    System.out.println("Server is waiting for client request");
    Socket s = ss.accept();

    System.out.println("Client connected");


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String str = null;
    str = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("Client Data: " +str);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that the client is never closing the socket, which causes the connection to be reset on some operating systems.

Comment: I added s.close(); at the end of my client code, it worked, thanks!